# Global hotkey doesn't work even though RegisterHotKey returns true

Tags: c#, activex, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I need an activeX which handles global hotkey: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

The code below is supposed to do this when I call this ActiveX from IE.

I see the result of `RegisterHotKey` is true which means that the hotkey has been registered ok.

But I don't see that any messages come to the ThreadPreprocessMessage method. Why?

```
namespace Kosmala.Michal.ActiveXTest{
    public class ActiveXObject : NativeWindow, IDisposable {
        public const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
        private IntPtr pFoundWindow ;

        public ActiveXObject(){
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("constructor<<");
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
            foreach (Process p in processes){
                pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
            }
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("pFoundWindow:" + pFoundWindow);
            SetupHotKey(pFoundWindow);
            ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage += ComponentDispatcher_ThreadPreprocessMessage;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("constructor>>");
        }

        void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadPreprocessMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled){
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("inside handler");
            if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY){
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("inside handler");
            }
        }

        private void SetupHotKey(IntPtr handle){
            bool res = RegisterHotKey(handle, GetType().GetHashCode(), 0x0004, 0x42); //Shift + b
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("SetupHotKey res:"+res);
        }

        public void Dispose(){
            UnregisterHotKey(_host.Handle, GetType().GetHashCode());
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install a hotkey in a window that belongs to another process. The documentation for [RegisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) says:

> This function cannot associate a hot
>   key with a window created by another
>   thread.

It doesn't even work with multiple threads in the *same* process, so it can't possibly work with threads from *other* processes.

Comment: Is this because I use ActiveX? Is there any solution?

Answer (score -1):

RegisterHotKey() is only for application hot keys, that is shortcut keys on a specific window.  Global hotkeys are registered differently - see [Hot Key Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775233%28VS.85%29.aspx).

There is also a project on Code Project, [System Hot Keys](http://hotkey.codeplex.com/), to do that in .NET.